# SQL Statement to update the date

Tags: sql, ms-access, date, sql-update

I have a string `1993-08-02 00:00:00.0` and I would like to update the date field in a Access Table

This is what I have but it is not working.

```
UPDATE [Table] SET `Birthdate` = '1993-08-02 00:00:00.0' WHERE `ID` = 000
```

Comment: Which version of access you are using and a bit more info on the table structure?

Comment: Access 2000 file format but I can make it 2003 format if that is better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates are not strings, but either of the following will result in a date:

```
DATE [Table] SET `Birthdate` = CDate('1993-08-02 00:00:00.0') WHERE `ID` = 000
```

(see the [documentation for CDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dt118h2(VS.85).aspx))

```
DATE [Table] SET `Birthdate` = #08/02/1993# WHERE `ID` = 000
```

Comment: The first one didn't work for me but the second one worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: The first one assumes you are using the Jet/ACE expression service. Given that you failed to specify the environment from which you are calling Jet, it's no wonder you got one answer that didn't work for you.

Comment: Late comment for latecomers: Just using a macro to create an update statement contained completely within Access, the first one worked perfectly for me.