# I can't get this MS Access SQL UPDATE statement to work

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am currently making a case tracker within MS Access and cannot get the below `UPDATE` code that is located in a subform to work. I've tried Googling this but to no avail.

All the data is stored in a main table called `tblCaseTrackerLoad`. This table has 98 columns in it. I also have a subform called `tblBulkAssign subform` which reads from 5 columns from within `tblCaseTrackerLoad` with the following query (which is placed in the Record Source fields of the Data tab):

```
SELECT tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Select], tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Case Status], tblCaseTrackerLoad. 
[Customer Name], tblCaseTrackerLoad.Account_Key, tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Case_Owner] FROM 
tblCaseTrackerLoad WHERE (((tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Case Status])="To be assigned"));
```

Here are the field types:

`tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Select]` is a Yes/No field 
`tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Case Status]` is a Short Text field  
`tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Customer Name]` is a Short Text field 
`tblCaseTrackerLoad.Account_Key` is a Large Number field 
`tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Case_Owner]` is a Short Text field

The above code works perfectly and when the subform is loaded, I can see the rows of data that where the "Case Status = To Be Assigned". This is shown in a table format.

What I am trying to make happen in when the subform is loaded, the user ticks boxes in the *Select* field (as many or as few as they need to select), then they click a button which loads a different form containing all the users that the case could be assigned to. A user is selected and then the code executes and is supposed to assign the cases to the users by way of an update statement to update the table "tblCaseTrackerLoad".

Here is my code for the execution of the `UPDATE` statement:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblCaseTrackerLoad SET [Case_Owner] = " & "'" & 
txtAssignToFromAssignToUserForm & "'" & ", [Case Status] = ""Assigned"", tblCaseTrackerLoad. 
[Date Assigned] = " & Assigned Timestamp & ", WHERE [Select] = Yes AND [Case_Owner] IS NULL;"

Debug. Print strSQL

' Execute the SQL Command
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

When ran, the error I get says "Run-Time error '3144': Syntax error in UPDATE statement."

Here is the output of Debug. Print

```
UPDATE tblCaseTrackerLoad SET [Case_Owner] = 'Craig Hogan', [Case Status] = "Assigned", tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Date Assigned] = 10/02/2022 07:36:13, WHERE [Select] = Yes AND [Case_Owner] IS NULL;
```

For reference:

1. `txtAssignToFromAssignToUserForm` is the value that is passed from the form to select who to assign the cases to, back into this subform. This box is successfully receiving the users name.
2. `AssignedTimeStamp` is a bit of code just above the `UPDATE` query which says `Dim AssignedTimeStamp As Date  AssignedTimeStamp = Now`

Although the `tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Date Assigned]` field is not referenced within the subform, it is still a valid field in the main table `tblCaseTrackerLoad` and is of type "Date/Time".

It's bound to be some silly little thing that I haven't done but I have spent approx. 4 hours trying to sort this out now and cannot seem to find the solution.

Please can someone educate me on where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Try to never use keywords like `select` as column names, also don't use forbidden chars like space in column names. You're only making your life harder.

Comment: Check quotes. Use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma before the "WHERE" clause.  Remove that comma.

```
UPDATE tblCaseTrackerLoad 
SET [Case_Owner] = 'Craig Hogan', [Case Status] = "Assigned", tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Date Assigned] = 10/02/2022 07:36:13
WHERE [Select] = Yes AND [Case_Owner] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi @Davo, thank you for your reply. I have removed the comma and now have a different error which says "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '10/02/2022 07:43:09'. 

The updated code is now:

`strSQL = "UPDATE tblCaseTrackerLoad SET [Case_Owner] = " & "'" & txtAssignToFromAssignToUserForm & "'" & ", [Case Status] = ""Assigned"", tblCaseTrackerLoad.[Date Assigned] = " & AssignedTimeStamp & " WHERE [Select] = Yes AND [Case_Owner] IS NULL;"`

Any ideas on how to resolve this one?

Comment: I think it has to do with the format of the datestamp. I am not super familiar with the Access implementation of SQL, but you could try putting single quotes and/or # around the date stamp.     [Date Assigned] = '#" AssignedTimeStamp "#' WHERE...

Comment: Some info about updating dates within Access: 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781315/sql-statement-to-update-the-date

Comment: thank you!! - your comments about removing the comma and wrapping the AssignedTimeStamp in '#" AssignedTimeStamp "#' worked a charm. I did have to change the field type to Short Text instead of Date/Time (for those that encounter the same issue).

Comment: I highly recommend to use [ADO Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters) instead of concatenated SQL strings. It saves you all the hassle of data formatting, i.e. date var -> string. You simply pass the VB(A) date variable to the parameter and ADO will take care of it. Just like it does with strings that e.g. have an embedded `'` which you would need to escape manually otherwise. ADO does this for you too.